# Selecting User Agent for Android Devices in Varnish

Tags: android, browser, user-agent, varnish

Here's the present state in my Varnish.
My question is, what is the best configuration for Android devices?

> if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "iPhone") {
>       set req.http.User-Agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_3 like Mac OS X; en_us) AppleWebKit/525.18.1 (KHTML, like Gecko)";
>   }   else if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "iPad") {
>       set req.http.User-Agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 4_3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8H7 Safari/6533.18.5";   }   else if
>   (req.http.User-Agent ~ "Android") {
>       // we don't do anything for Android devices right now since there
>       // are just too many different ones.
>       //
>       // We could cache two versions, one mobile, one table for each
>       // Android 2.0-2.4, however, we try to leave it be right now and
>       // see how big the cache gets.   }   else {
>       set req.http.User-Agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; VOSA 1.0)";   } }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a good devicedetect.vcl written by Varnish software themselves. It's alot easier to use than and provides more device types to grow with. It has a good android detection for both tablet and phones separated as well. You can find the source and good documentation on how to use it at:

https://github.com/varnish/varnish-devicedetect

Using it myself and have only good experience with the matching.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reference. Should I have further query I will ask you. :)

Comment: @Clarence I have a question on this URL here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482395/any-other-steps-needed-after-adding-this-device-detection-code-in-varnish-for-ub

Answer (score 0):

@clarence suggestion to use varnish-devicedetect is a good one . for noobs like me who prefer a simple setup and detailed explanation. try out this tutorial at [atomic object](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/02/11/varnish-cache-mobile-devices/) .

its pretty simple,straight forward and only need to add few vcl rules to the configuraration file