# Ubuntu Varnish mobile detection results in to page not found?

Tags: python, caching, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, varnish

I am trying this example to do mobile device detection using varnish
https://github.com/varnish/varnish-devicedetect/blob/master/INSTALL.rst

I implemented Example 1 and now trying to test it via the testing tools at the bottom
https://github.com/varnish/varnish-devicedetect/blob/master/INSTALL.rst#testing-tools

I am unsure how to work this part, it gives me Page not Found

```
Now you can access it through:

http://localhost:5911/devicetest/ , or
http://localhost:6081/devicetest/ # Change 6081 into your Varnish listening port.
```

For the backend example I am using port no 5912, which I updated in the devicedetect-dev.vcl file and backend/example-backend.py file.

When I do mywebsiteaddress:5912/set_ua_device/ , I get a Page not found error.
I am unsure what I am missing in this case?

I also tried Example 3 install and it works fine for me. Although I would prefer to enable the device detection via Example 1. I am trying this on ubuntu AWS server.

**Update:**
After restarting both the apache and varnish. I can now achieve step1 of testing-tools and a cookie is being set. Although mywebsiteaddress:5912/set_ua_device/ still results in a **404 Page not found**

Not sure what I am missing here.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for people coming on this page searching how to serve for different devices using varnish . other than varnish-devicedetect you can also try a different solution .

try this tutorial from [atomic object](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/02/11/varnish-cache-mobile-devices/)

they follow a very simple approach and all you need to do is add few vcl rules, suited for noobs like me